# Coordinate length to pixel length mapping in ImageCanvas

Tags: openlayers-3

I want to draw circles in an image canvas. I'm able to get pixel values from coordinate values by calling **map.coordinateToPixel**.

For radius, how can I map a coordinate distance to pixel length?

For instance, if my radius is 60 arc minutes, it goes from 50 degrees to 51 degrees. In a vector layer, the underlying framework manages the translation to pixels depending on the zoom level. However, for an ImageCanvas, I need to specify that myself. Is there a method to do that? I know I might have to dig into the code, but I was wondering if there's an inherent solution somebody already knows of.

**An alternate option I've considered is:**

1. Get the coordinate at pixel (0,0)
2. Get the coordinate at (radiusLogitude, 0)
3. Find the diff between the #2 - #1 on the Longitude and use that as my radius

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this example can help you: http://acanimal.github.io/thebookofopenlayers3/chapter03_04_imagecanvas.html it draw a set of random pie charts (but without taking into account pixel ratio).

Note, the `canvasFunction` you use receives five parameters that can help you determine the pixel size: `function(extent, resolution, pixelRatio, size, projection)`